# Create an Overlay on a building (in a campus university)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, mapquest

I am working on my project this year and my task is to create an iPhone app that will interact with campus' buildings. I am running iOS6 and for this reason I can't use Apple Maps. After hours of search I found MapQuest(OSM). At the moment, I have achieved to draw an Overlay on a building, but this requires a lot of time, in order to find and pass the correct lat/lng. In the past I have worked on an Android phone and I was using KML files to draw routes etc. Until now, I can't find anything similar for MapQuest (points slightly differs from Google Maps).

Do anyone knows an efficiency way to retrieve exact lat/lng points for a building and draw its Overlay using MapQuest? It is important to achieve that, because my main goal is to make that building or area clickable for the user. Please help, I am lost.

Thanks in advance